# Why does $\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\sin{x}dx=1$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I know what the sine function is, and why its graph is a wave. I know what a definite integral is. But I don't understand why this integral happens to be $1$. Can anyone explain it to me?

Note: Someone tried to edit this saying that I know how to evaluate definite integrals. I don't. I know what they are though.

Comment: If evaluating the integral with the fundamental theorem of calculus does not give you insight, you should think about why the fundamental theorem of calculus is true.

Comment: We have $f(x)= \sin x$. In order to integrate, you need to find the antiderivate $F$ which is  $-\cos x$ and then just fill in the upper and lower limits of your integral.
In general: $\int_a^{b} f(x)\, dx= F(b) - F(a)$

Comment: Actually, I couldn't agree more. (That goes for both comments, but was meant for the first.)

Comment: I wonder what the reason for the downvoter downvoting the answers and the question itself. I see that the question, sigma's answer, and my answer have all received downvotes.

Comment: Although I didn't down vote I feel like a Riemann sum would be more helpful in this circumstance . @user342209

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin x\,dx=-\cos x\mid_0^\frac{\pi}{2}=0 -(-1)=1$

$F(x)\mid_a^{b}$ means $F(b)-F(a)$

So in general $\int_a^{b} f(x)\, dx= F(b) - F(a)$

Answer (score 5):

The value $I$
$$
I = \int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\sin x \,dx = 1
$$
can be [interpreted as area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) between the graph of $\sin$ and the $x$-axis.

$$
A 
= \int\limits_0^{\pi/2} \lvert \sin x \rvert \,dx 
= \int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\sin x \,dx 
= I
$$

See the image below which uses a unit raster of $0.2 = 1/5$, so a unit square has area $1/25$. You will see that roughly 25 units fit the area.

Note the excess area to the right of $x=1.5$ of about $5\times 0.1=0.5$.

[image: area interpretation]

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(x)dx=-\cos(x)\large|^{\pi/2}_0$$ Can you take it from here?

In case you mean to ask what the 'meaning' of the Integral is, the Integral simply computes the area between the graphs of $\sin(x)$ and the $X$ axis between $x=0$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: I can't give any better answer than this, but I suspect that the OP wants something else (assuming they do, in fact, understand definite integrals.)

Comment: Perhaps the OP wanted to know what the Integral actually represents?

Comment: Actually, this works for me, but I have to wait 9 minutes (at the time of this comment being posted) to accept this answer.

Comment: Read the above comment.

Comment: I actually would like to know the meaning of the pipe/vertical bar in the equation in this answer. (I get the idea though.)

Comment: $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(x)|_a^b=F(b)-F(a)$$ when the function $F(x)$ is defined at both $a$ and $b$. In case they are not defined, you have to take limits depending on the Interval of Integration. Note that $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$.